# How do I set a value for existing rows when creating a new timestamp column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
Study   id
Pepsi   1
Coke    2
Sprite  3
```

I need to add a new column `timestamp` in the above table. i.e, study creation time and date will be stored in this column. What value should I have set for existing rows? Or should the "Timestamp" column have a value only for newly created rows?

I have used the following query to add the new column:

```
alter table Study add Timestamp datetime
```

Comment: This completely depends on your requirements. Either allow them to be null or pick some default value and set them all to that (and then make the column non-nullable)

Comment: **Warning:** `TIMESTAMP` is a **datatype** in SQL Server, and that word is a reserved / keyword. Try to avoid using that - use something else (like `StudyCreated` or whatever you like) for your column name!

Comment: Agreed with @marc_s - please, please, please don't call this column `timestamp` - call it what it is, like `StudyCreationTime` or even just `CreationTime`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell you what value you should set for existing rows - that is up to you to decide. If you can somehow retrieve the creation time by piecing together other information, then perhaps you can do this one by one, or you could just leave the existing rows to `NULL`.

Setting a default like `GETDATE()` for the column, and setting it to `NOT NULL`, forces all of the existing rows to inherit the current date and time - and you won't be able to set those back to `NULL`. I'm quite opposed to using garbage token values like `1900-01-01` to represent unknown, and I also don't believe in modifying the code to say something like "if the date is October 8, 2013 then that's because we just didn't know." So I would suggest adding a `NULLable` column with a default:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Study ADD CreationTime DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
GO
```

Note that if you leave the column nullable, then the `DEFAULT` constraint is only useful if DML never sets it to `NULL`. If an `INSERT` statement, for example, explicitly places `NULL` there, the default is ignored. A way around this is to use a trigger (just like you would handle an update):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.StudyCreationTime
ON dbo.Study
FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE s
    SET s.CreationTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM dbo.Study AS s
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i
    ON s.StudyID = i.StudyID;
END
GO
```

Comment: I see the end result you're going for and think that's a fine strategy. I would probably still use a default instead of a trigger. Adding a default to a column that is nullable won't update existing rows.

Comment: @Tim the trigger is only an additional suggestion in the event that they still want the column populated correctly even if certain DML overrides the default with an explicit NULL. I've re-worded to make that more clear.

Comment: Gotcha, I've never thought of that scenario. When the choice is yours, do you use triggers, defaults, or the application to populate these types of columns?

Comment: @Tim I much prefer a NOT NULL DEFAULT. I never trust the application and I don't use a trigger unless I have to. Usually when I use a trigger I use an INSTEAD OF trigger, since if there is business logic that might fail/roll back the operation, I may as well prevent it instead of allowing it to happen and then rolling it back.

Answer (score 0):

> what value should i have to set for previous studies

This would have to be defined by your business. This doesn't require a technical answer, so no one here can tell you what is right.

> I have used below query to adding new column:
>
> `alter table Study add Timestamp datetime`

This will work just fine, though this will allow nulls.  I might suggest making this column non-null, adding a default, and changing the name of the column slightly since `timestamp` is a reserved word in SQL Server (a datatype that has not much to do with dates or times):

```
alter table Study add CreateDate datetime not null default current_timestamp;
```

Note that this will set all rows to the current date and time, so you may want to update them if you have more accurate data.  Alternatively, simply create the column as nullable and existing rows won't get the default value, but rather null instead.

Another choice you might have to make is whether to use local time or UTC time (e.g. `default getutcdate()`).  You might want to use the same time that your servers use or that other "CreateDate" columns use.

Comment: But Tim, this sets all existing rows to the current time, which is incorrect and potentially problematic.

Comment: Very true.  The balance between providing the most complete answer possible and hitting submit to get upvotes before other answers: I don't know it.